# PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement pl/sql oracle trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers

hi I create a trigger but I did encounter an error and i don't know what to do

```
create or replace trigger OneMillion 
before insert on RESERVATION 
for each row 
DECLARE 
         ligne PASSAGER%ROWTYPE;
         NPRESVOL number;
begin
    select count(*) INTO NPRESVOL from RESERVATION;
        IF NPRESVOL = 36 THEN
            SELECT * FROM PASSAGER WHERE IDPS = :NEW.IDPS;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (' Vous Este le client 1 million sur le vol .' );
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (' NOM : ' || ligne.NOMPS);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (' Prenom : '|| ligne.PRENOMPS );
            DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (' ID PASSAGER : '|| ligne.IDPS );
        END IF;
end;

and this is the log error 

Trigger ONEMILLION compiled

LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
7/4       PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
Errors: check compiler log
```

i don't know what to do in this case PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `INTO` in the second `SELECT`:

```
SELECT * INTO ligne FROM PASSAGER WHERE IDPS = :NEW.IDPS;
```